# Inserting a new table column to include IFELSE results of previous columns

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

[image]

Column L containing boutique numbers and Column AB where the new inserted column containing the boutique codes will be.

As my title suggests, I am hoping to add a new column to a table containing IF ELSE values from a previous column (Column L, which contains the values A,B,C,D,E depending on the boutique). My code is below

```
Sub BoutiqueCodes()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim cel As Range
Dim boutique As String[enter image description here][1]
Dim codes As Integer
boutique = Range("L, L").Value
'the boutique values come from Column L
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_1")
    With tbl
        .ListColumns.Add.Name = "Code"
        For Each cel In .ListColumns("Code").DataBodyRange.Cells
            If boutique = "A" Then
                codes = 506
             ElseIf boutique = "B" Then
                codes = 606
            ElseIf boutique = "C" Then
                codes = 706
            ElseIf boutique = "D" Then
                codes = 611
            ElseIf boutique = "E" Then
                codes = 612
            Else
                codes = 0
            End If
            cel.Value = codes
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I am going wrong with the `boutique = Range("L, L").Value` line. I am sure of that. What I want in the new column is the corresponding codes for the boutique. Previously, I did not have the `boutique = Range("L, L").Value` line however all my code values were coming out as 0. Any help would be great. thanks

Comment: Is boutique the value of the cell in column L in the same row you're evaluating?

Comment: Sorry, i'll amend the question accordingly. I have a list of values in column L (A,B,C,D and E). and I want there corresponding codes to appear in a new column at the end of the table. I probably didnt make that clear.

Comment: Sure. a screenshot would help.

Comment: `boutique = Range("L, L").Value` is wrong in many ways.  `"L,L"` is not a valid range reference.  And there is no way a string variable can be made equal to a multi-cell range. Without an example of your data, it's hard to make recommendations. But it seems as if a simple worksheet formula could do the job.

Comment: hi guys, i have added a screenshot - let me know if that helps

Comment: Does the column Boutique belong to `Table_1`?

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add Column to Table With Calculation

**A Quick Fix Using `Offset`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub BoutiqueCodes()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim boutique As String
    Dim codes As Long
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_1")
    With tbl
        .ListColumns.Add.Name = "Code"
        ColumnOffset = .ListColumns("Boutique").Index _
                     - .ListColumns("Code").Index
        For Each cel In .ListColumns("Code").DataBodyRange.Cells
            boutique = cel.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Value
            If boutique = "A" Then
                codes = 506
            ElseIf boutique = "B" Then
                codes = 606
            ElseIf boutique = "C" Then
                codes = 706
            ElseIf boutique = "D" Then
                codes = 611
            ElseIf boutique = "E" Then
                codes = 612
            Else
                codes = 0
            End If
            cel.Value = codes
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```